# An error arises in Matlab: Undefined function or variable 'removeStopWords'

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab R2017B with text analytics toolbox installed(I have checked by searching get add-ons). I have written a simple function which is the following:

```
function x=test()
    s='i am a boy and u r a grl';
    disp(removeStopWords(s));
end
```

And it shows the following error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'removeStopWords'.
```

Then, I have tried following in command window:

```
which removeStopWords
```

and it shows

```
'removeStopWords' not found.
```

Would you please shed light on this issue explaining why is this happening?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

removeStopWords was introduced in R2018b.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/textanalytics/ref/tokenizeddocument.removestopwords.html?s_tid=doc_ta#function_removeStopWords_seealso

Comment: in this case, should i upgrade the toolbox or is there any function available for R2017b?

Comment: You cannot upgrade toolbox alone. You need to upgrade your matlab. You can remove a given character array from a string in R2017b, so you can do your task manually. But if possible, I suggest upgrading because in last two relases MATLAB added a lot of support for strings and string operations.